# Harddrive showing as Invalid

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-management

My system is set up with two hard drives, one solid state drive to hold the OS and some other minor files that aren't important and one is a 1TB HDD that holds all the rest of the random files.

At the end of the Windows 10 upgrade window I migrate my system up to windows 10 from windows 7. Everything went fine but I was running into problems with drivers and things while using windows 10 so I decided to revert back to Windows 7. Since I completed the roll back the 1TB drive has been having multiple issues, including occasionally not registering on boot requiring a reboot before being usable and mysteriously partioning itself so instead of one large block roughly 1TB in size it now shows as two 80GB partitions and one roughly 740GB partition with the 80GB partitions basically unusable.

Due to these issues I've decided to replace the 1TB drive with a new 4TB drive.  I've replaced the 1TB drive with the 4TB drive in the box and now I am trying to use a USB to SATA connector to transfer the data from the 1TB drive to the 4TB drive but when I plug in the 1TB drive through the USB port it is showing up like this:

[image: Disk appearance during disk management screen]

I can right-click on the Disk and choose Initialize Disk but once I complete the next screen I get a message saying "The device is not ready." No matter what I choose during the dialog.

Is there anything that I can do to get the OS to recognize the 1TB drive?

If not, is there any program that could be used to get the information that is on the 1TB drive onto either the 4TB drive or a USB stick or some form of other storage that I could use as an intermediary?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be caused by several symptoms including a corrupted MBR or an invalid partition you can try the following :

Right click on my computer > manage > disk management . Locate your drive and initialize it with MBR .

Option 2 : 
Download minitool partition and locate your drive after installation right click on it and select rebuild MBR . Or you can alternatively chose recover partition .

Note : I do not guarantee that your data will be kept I highly suggest you get your HDD plugged into another PC or enclosure to another PC to check wether you can access it or not and backup your data .

Comment: I attempted your first suggestion and that was when i was getting the "The device is not ready." message. I found another SATA cable and was able to plug in all three hard drives directly to the motherboard at the same time. It seems to have worked and I'm transferring all the files as I type this. So I'm guessing the source of the main problem was the USB/SATA connector that I was trying to use.

Comment: Good to hear just to be on safe side run some diagnostic on it

Comment: Once the transfer is complete I'll look into it a bit more.